# Problems with signature --- openssl_sign

Tags: java, php, openssl, rsa

In JAVA code (BouncyCastle lib) we create signature using private key. Code below.
We have a task to get the same signature using PHP --- using the same private key.
Try to use PHP code like

```
openssl_sign($plainText, /*&*/$signature, $private_key);
```

But signature that we get in PHP is not the same with signature that we get in JAVA.

May be we have problem because openssl_sign() function doesnt' work with "MD5withRSA" --- may be somebody know how to solve this problem ?

```
  protected byte[] sign(PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] plainText) {
    byte[] signature = null;
    try {
      Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("MD5withRSA");
      sig.initSign(privateKey);
      sig.update(plainText);
      signature = sig.sign();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return signature;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't help you out a ton with openssl but here's how you'd do it with [phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/):

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
//$rsa->setPassword('password');
$rsa->loadKey('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'); // private key

$plaintext = '...';

$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$rsa->setHash('md5');
$signature = $rsa->sign($plaintext);

echo bin2hex($signature);
```