# PHP openssl_sign() - different result from SoapUi

Tags: php, xml, soapui, php-openssl

I have to send a soap request, which part should be signed using certificate and algorithm = http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1. I have to generate it in PHP.

I use SoapUi application to verify, if my final outgoing request is correct. After configuring SoapUi (with the same certificate) I have a request, which is accepted by external (receiver's) system. So I can view in SoapUi, how the final outgoing xml looks like.

Because there is no fine-working implementation in PHP, which would allow to successfully sign **a part of** outgoing message, I prepared my own piece of code. I have extended php SoapClient and now I have almost the same outgoing xml, like in SoapUi. Comparing to xml generated by SoapUi my message is different only in one field: "SignatureValue". The rest of xml is the same.

The "SignatureValue" field contains base64_encode($signature). $signature is calculate by the following php code:

```
openssl_sign($signedInfo_canonized, $signature, $private_key_id, 'sha1WithRSAEncryption');
```

where:

- $signedInfo_canonized is the result of c14N() function on "SignedInfo" xml tag. This tag is the same as generated by SoapUi. It contains the same (proper) DigestValue.
- $signature is the signature result.
- $private_key_id is =

  $private_key_id = openssl_pkey_get_private('file://'.constant('PRIVATE_KEY_PATH'), constant('PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD'));

Additionally, the signature verification in php returns true:

```
  openssl_verify($signedInfo_canonized, $signature, $public_key_id);
```

So everything works fine and there is no error, but my "SignatureValue" tag, created as above, contains "`HyaVsqoML0 ...` " base64 string, but should contain "`YsSMvMYfm75 ...` ".

I tried a few different canonization methods of "SignedInfo" node and each time  received different signature, but each time different then in SoapUi.

I also cannot debug SoapUi to look inside and check, how the individual parts of above process looke like in Java.

I found a few articles and questions about the same problem (for example this one: [Problems with signature --- openssl_sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399159/problems-with-signature-openssl-sign)), they look similar, but none of solutions worked for me.

Any ideas to help? ;-)

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no; java developers prepared for me a command-line library, which uses the same openssl and c14N functions as SoupUi.

Comment: could you share the source code for that CLI java program? I need sign documents from PHP and I am helpless